# Is it possible to start a WPF Application from another, with a specific form

Tags: asp.net, wpf

```
private void btnRun_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    Process p = new Process(); 
    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("c://WPFApplication1.exe"); 
    p.Start(); 
}
```

I start the other application from my application using this; but I want to go to a particular form.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use a command line argument when you start the process:

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "formname";
```

Then in the target project, retrieve the command line argument in *Application_Startup*, and open the form:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    string formName = e.Args[0];
    this.StartupUri = formName;
}
```